# How to set an app as also a Library in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, shared-libraries

I've an app `X` that is also library for other apps. Its default state is as a Library. When I want to compile `X` as an app, I change that in Eclipse using `Project > Properties > Android`, and (un)clicking in `Is Library`.

How can I do this in Android Studio without editing the `X` build.gradle file line

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

since this is not convenient and gives tons of errors for the other apps?

Thanks!
L.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik this is the only way. The solution to giving tons of errors by other apps is to export the project as an .aar library, put it into libs folder of other projects and import it via build.gradle.